# Is it possible to capture a web signature from opera mini 8/win mob 6

Tags: php, opera, capture, signature

I was wondering if anyone knew of a method of capturing a customer signature from opera mini 8  on winmobile 6 , and having the signature save the image to the server?

Failing that, I'm going to have to create a client side app, but that defeats the purpose a little.

Comment: I think you're referring to Opera Mobile. The latest version of Opera Mini is 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

you mean testing if they're using opera mini on windows mobile?

for that you want a useragent detection script

<?php

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini')>0) 
  {
  $mobile=true;
  }

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows')>0)&& (!strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'phone')>0) )
  {
  $mobile=false;
  }
?>